# net::ERR_INVALID_URL for Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, get

I would like to utilize javascript to sync photos uploaded to my webpage to Google drive but faced the error:

Error log in browser console shows:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL

**HTML,Javascript:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="input" value="">
    <div id="fileUrl"></div>
    <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script>
    (function($) {
    var appUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx8gZwY_T8-h2tKyquxKmGfug5j_njAe4m9t6MnBnQYee4SbfI/exec",
    file, fileReader;

    $("#input").change(function() {
    file = this.files[0];
    if (file) {
    fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = getFileInfo;
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
   
    }
    });

    function getFileInfo(evt) {
    var fileName = file.name,
    fileType = file.type,
    dataUrl = evt.target.result,
    base64Data = dataUrl.split(",")[1];
    uploadFile(fileName, fileType, base64Data);

    }

    function uploadFile(fileName, fileType, base64Data) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    data: {
    "fileName": fileName,
    "fileType": fileType,
    "base64Data": base64Data
    },
    url: appUrl,
    success: function(fileUrl) { 
    $("#fileUrl").html(fileUrl);
    },
    error: function(e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
    console.log('ajax error');
    }
    });
    }
    })(jQuery);
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

**Google APP Script(API to fetch my get from ajax):**

```
var folderId = "1riQpaq34Gz9SWoaAqSLspaorjBpQ0SJd",
folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

function doGet(e) {
var para = e.parameter,
fileName = para.fileName,
fileType = para.fileType,
base64Data = para.base64Data;

return getFileUrl(fileName, fileType, base64Data);
}

function getFileUrl(fileName, fileType, base64Data) {
var data = Utilities.base64Decode(base64Data),
blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, fileType, fileName),
file = folder.createFile(blob),
fileUrl = file.getUrl();

return ContentService.createTextOutput(fileUrl);
}
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this code locally, you'll have to use a fully qualified URL to include the jQuery library, like this:

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
```